# I wanted to make a separate method for listeners in the root view but it throws NPE

Tags: tornadofx

I have a `borderpane` as the root view and it was getting kind of big so I wanted to divide them into small chunks… with `View`s there is no problem, I can easily separate them into files and classes.

The problem I am having is that when I want to make a separate method for `root` view's listeners, it is throwing NPE.

This was my original code:

```
override val root = borderpane {
    addClass(rootStyle)
    paddingAll = 10.0

    // listeners
        setOnMouseEntered { scaleUp() }

        setOnMouseExited { scaleDown() }
    // end listeners
    center {...}
    }
}
```

This is my current code that throws NPE:

```
override val root = borderpane {
    addClass(rootStyle)
    paddingAll = 10.0

    setListeners() // I added this
    center {...}
    }
}

private fun setListeners(){
     with(root) {
        setOnMouseEntered { scaleUp() }

        setOnMouseExited { scaleDown() }
    }
}
```

I tried it without `with(root)` but IDE highlighted them as errors.
I also tried to call the method in `onBeforeShow()`, it didn't throw any exceptions but listeners didn't work.

What is a proper way to handle this? In Android I easily make `setListeners()` method and call it from `onCreate()`. What would be an optimal equivalent of this in TornadoFX?

**Edited:**
I found a working code but still I am not sure if it is an optimal way... if you have better ways to handle this type of situations, feel free to add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wheeee, it was right under my nose. I passed `this` (`borderpane`) into a method and it worked as expected.

```
override val root = borderpane{
    setListeners(this)
}


private fun setListeners(borderPane: BorderPane) {
    with(borderPane) {
        setOnMouseEntered { scaleUp() }
        setOnMouseExited { scaleDown() }
    }
}
```

Comment: But still I am not sure if it is an optimal way... if you have better ways to handle this type of situations, feel free to add your answers.